# Why do system tend to attain thermal equilibrium anyway?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

Ok, so I was reading a chapter on thermodynamics (introduction), which built its content on the idea that two systems separated by a diathermic wall will tend to attain thermal equilibrium with each other and the surrounding ( in case they are also separated by surrounding with diathermic wall).
I have a simple question in my mind,
why do systems tend to attain thermal equilibrium anyway?
Any explanation, bulk or microscopic will do, both are also welcome.

Comment: It is the most likely state: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/377428/137289

Comment: @Pieter thanks for the help, but I think it does not answer the exact "why" question I asked

Comment: There is no purpose, systems do not "strive" to "attain" equilibrium, no real reason "why". It is just random exchanges of energy. Until the probability is maximal.

Comment: @Adi Regarding AbhirupMukherjee and dmckee discussion below,  check out the Hyperphysics web site on "What is Temperature". It shows how entropy change provides a "more reliable approach to temperature" than the more intuitive idea of high speed molecules hitting low speed molecules. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

If one system, say a fluid, is at a higher temperature, it will have more kinetic energy than the other fluid. Hence it will continue to impart kinetic energy to the other fluid through the diathermal wall, via collisions. Of course the fluid at lower temperature also transfers kinetic energy to the 'hotter' fluid, but the former process is more intense. The result is a net transfer of energy from hotter to cooler, via collisions. This happens until their average thermal energies become equal; the rate of transfer of energies become equal on either side.

Comment: No. Equal temperature does not imply equal energy or equal kinetic energy or equal average thermal energy.

Comment: @Peter, isn't kinetic energy proportional to temperature?

Comment: No, not necessarily. It is only valid in classical systems. It is not how temperature is defined. Quantum effects are important also in melting ice etc.

Comment: To be a little more helpful, the strict proportionality of temperature to the mean kinetic energy of the constituents is a feature of kinetic theory applied to *ideal gasses*. You can generalize the idea a little more by considering the mean internal energy per internal degree of freedom. But it is not a fundamental definition of temperature. That said, that model is a nice one to use to start answering the question.

Comment: @dmckee What is the most fundamental definition of temperature?

Comment: Levels of fundamentalness are not well defined. *A* fundamental definition (one suited to classical thermodynamics and many uses in statistical mechanics) is as the partial derivative of internal energy with respect to entropy. But of course, you can't use the definition until you have good definition of entropy and into the rabbit hole you go.

Comment: @dmckee Doesn't defining entropy as k*ln(W) salvage the situation?

Comment: Yes, and my preferred teaching approach starts that way. But look at the historical development of thermal physics to see just how late that notion came along. People dealt with the subject using the equilibrium and heat-engines model for *lifetimes* before the statistical basis got off the ground.

Comment: And it comes late in most of the curriculums as well..